# Number Theory question on divisibilty

Tags: elementary-number-theory

When all numbers which leave 47 as remainder divided by 779 are contained in a set; then how many different remainders are possible when all possible numbers of that set are divided by 95?

My thoughts on this :- numbers will be of form 779n+47 where n is an integer
now how shall I divide this with 95 ? will it be (779 mod 95)+47 ? I am not sure on how to start with the main solving, please help !

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the remainders you are looking for are parametrized by $\{19n+47:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and notice that 95 is divisible by $19$. Thus you would expect a periodic behaviour.

Comment: more specifically, a period of 5, since $19 \times 5 = 95$

Answer (score 2):

The numbers "which leave 47 as remainder divided by 779" are those which can be written
$$n=779k+47=(95\cdot8+19)k+47,\quad k\in\Bbb Z.$$
Modulo $95,$ these $n$'s are congruent to $19k+47,\quad k\in\Bbb Z$ and since $95=19\cdot5,$ all possible remainders are attained if we restrict to five consective integers $k,$ like $k\in\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}.$ That makes five remainders.